# Python error: 'dict' object is not callable

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to load my data so it stores in a dictionary of dictionaries. But I'm getting this error:

```
  self.user_rating(mid, {} )   #Dictionary of dictionaries = urating
  TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

This is the code for this particular method.

```
def load_r(self,file):
            f = open(file)
            for line in f:
                    line = line.rstrip()
                    components = line.split("::")
                    uid = components[0]
                    mid = components[1]
                    urating = components[2]
            self.user_rating(mid, {} )  ###Line of interest   
            f.close()
```

The dictionary is supposed to be something like

**GOAL: dictionary[mid, dictionary2[uid, urating]]**
as in dictionary[key, dictionary2[key, value]]

Am I supposed to set the self.user_rating line equal to something? Thank you!

---

EDIT (update): When I try to call

```
self.mdb.set_user_m_rating(41, 787, 2)
```

I get an error in the line

```
self.user_rating[mid][uid] = rating
```

This is after changing the line to self.user_rating[mid] = {}
but later calling self.user_rating[mid][uid]=rating in another method.

Comment: Do you mean `self.user_rating[mid] = {}`?

Comment: With that, can I do this?---------------------------------------------                                              def set_user_movie_rating(self, uid, mid, rating):
                self.user_rating[mid][uid] = rating ?

Comment: It would be so much easier for everyone if you posted a sample data file

Comment: The data file just has ratings contained in in this fashion (yes, there are occasions where the same users rated multiple things)---
uid::mid::Rating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no magic special syntax for dictionaries of dictionaries. You just use the normal dictionary syntax twice to get to the values of the inner dicts.

`self.user_rating` is a dict.

You look up a subdict like this

```
self.user_rating[mid]  # the value here is a subdict
```

and so the value in the subdict is found by adding another key lookup

```
self.user_rating[mid][uid]
```

And of course to create an empty subdict

```
self.user_rating[mid] = {}
```

Then add a rating like this

```
self.user_rating[mid][uid] = rating
```

If the `uid` might already have a value, you can test for that

```
if uid in self.user_rating[mid]:
    self.user_rating[mid][uid] = rating
else:
    self.user_rating[mid] = {uid: rating}
```

When you've worked out these basics, you should read the docs on `collections.defaultdict`

Comment: It's probably also worth noting that you can't do `self.user_rating[mid][uid] = rating`  if `self.user_rating[mid]` doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Thank you. How come though when I declared it as self.user_rating[mid] = {} , when I try to use self.user_rating[mid][uid] = rating in a different function it does not work properly?

Comment: @user3295674, can you post a self contained example that fails like that?

Comment: @gnibbler, thank you for helping me understand this, I've updated the question with extra information.